# How can I unmount bad mounting?

Tags: mount

I have did a wrong thing. I mounted
`/dev/mapper/vgpool-lvstuff7` to `/` , that is bad. How can I unmount that thing?

Comment: I have made a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/5tzvnlmzz/

Comment: @Hauke Of course you can mount filesystems over each other.

Comment: If you can still run `umount` (from some location), then just do `umount /dev/mapper/vgpool-lvstuff7`. Otherwise I'm afraid @Hauke is right: reboot.

Comment: Wont reboot kill my server?

Comment: @peterph I must admit I didn't give it a try. I remembered error messages "moint point is already in use" or something like that. But they may have been caused by something else. Indeed, it is possible to mount several volumes at the same directory.

Comment: Did you try (as root) `umount /dev/mapper/vgpool-lvstuff7` as @peterph suggested?

Comment: Yes I tried. It says its busy, can't unmount... :D

Comment: @user2301881 reboot shouldn't kill it. You might end up with dirty file systems (including rootfs), but a **clean** reboot should do be reasonably fine. If you can, you can also try the magic [`SysRq` key combos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses), if the reboot gets stuck.

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly suggest a reboot to cleanly fix things up.

But if you are against that, try `umount -l`.

Comment: `umount -l /`—I have just tested this on a VM—is a great way require a reboot. At least, if its actually the rootfs.

Comment: You don't have to give the logical volume...give the physical volume to be more specific!

Comment: An unmount is always done on the mount point, not the device (I assume this is what you mean by "physical volume" instead of "logical volume"). Check `man 2 umount` — the actual call to the kernel gives the mount point. When you pass the device (or label, or whatever else) to the `/sbin/umount`, the program is translating it to a mount point (via `/etc/mtab`, probably), and then passing that mount point to `umount2`.

Comment: @mdpc, yes, you do; mount knows nothing about LVM physical volumes.

Answer (score 2):

Mounting something on `/` hides all existing mounts. To recover from this, you'll need some way to issue a `mount` or `umount` system call as root.

If you run `umount /` with the `umount` program from `vgpool-lvstuff7`, it's going to fail because the volume will be in use by the very program doing the unmounting. I think `umount -l` will work: assuming that there aren't other programs running from `vgpool-lvstuff7` (if there are, kill them first), the volume will be unmounted when `umount` exits.

Another potential approach is to play with `mount --bind` and `mount --move`. Mount a `tmpfs` filesystem somewhere (`mkdir /z; mount -t tmpfs scratch /z; mkdir /z/root`) and try copying or creating a `mount` program there, and running `mount --bind / /z/root`. The volume `vgpool-lvstuff7` will then be accessible at `/z/root`. I'm not sure if you can move the root mount at that point though.

If you have no access to the `mount` program, that's ok, as long as you have a way to get a root shell and to `/proc`. You can access the original root as `/proc/1/root`. Although this looks like a useless symbolic link to `/`, it's in fact a magic link — dereferencing it brings you to the actual root partition of the program with PID 1 (init). So you'll always have `umount` accessible at `/proc/1/root/bin/umount`.

If you don't have `/proc`, another way to get the `umount` program would be to copy it from somewhere, or even just a small binary that just calls the `umount` syscall, or you could invoke the syscall from some interpreted language such as perl.

Comment: +1 for the `/proc/*/root`! I'm afraid in this particular case however it might not be possible - once you mount a data-only fs over rootfs, you have pretty much reached a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Check `/proc/mounts`, not `df`. It appears `df` is confused (probably because `/etc/mtab` is wrong).

If they were actually both mounted on `/`, then `df` would show the same stats (size, in use, free, percent) for both.